# django user model foreign key to company

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am beginning my first django project and would like to know which method is best for creating a relationship between `User` & `Company` models.

Option 1 - User existing django user model and create a user profile model

```
Class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Option 2 - Create custom user model

```
Class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    "all of the required user data -- left off for brevity"
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

I have no issue with the base user model, my concern is more related to performance IF the application grows to a larger scale.  I realize option 1 requires an additional database hit; however, I like the flexibility of having a UserProfile which can be modified to include additional criteria.

Which option would you prefer, or is there a better way?

Comment: I will go for creating UserProfile

Comment: Its better to create a UserProfile. In the future you may want to add some fields to that UserProfile and you will appreciate having it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to create the UserProfile to give additional flexibility.  While we don't know how the application will grow, we feel it is important to keep our domain as flexible as possible.  Thank you for all of the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

So it basically depends on the use case and scope of the application, if you know that you just care about user nmae, email add, pass mainly then i will go with in built User Profile that comes with django. Otherwise, I would prefer making another UserProfile, as you will have the flexibility to add more parameters and methods with respect to your project.